# GPG Suite cannot find Thomas Voegtlin's public key for Electrum

Tags: electrum, public-key

I'm trying to reinstall Electrum but cannot find Thomas Voegtlin's public key using GPG Suite, so cannot verify the downloaded Electrum software. Do I just need to keep trying or is there an alternative?

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be a folder in the Electrum repository where contributors share copies of their public keys: https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/tree/master/pubkeys

You should be able to download and import the key from there. I was also able to get a copy of the key from both keyserver.ubuntu.com and keys.openpgp.org, so I'm a bit surprised that it wouldn't work out of the box. Maybe do check twice that everything matches up.

Edit: When you import a key, it will only be known to your key database. However, if you want a level of trust to be associated with a key, you still need to specify that you trust the key. Perhaps this was the step that is missing?